# Django Oscar. How to add product?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

I'm a beginner in Python and Django.
I have installed django-oscar. Then I Configured it and started the server, it works.

Now, I don't understand `how to add a product`?

At the dashboard there is a button `Create new product`. But in order to add new product it asks to select product class and I can not find any product class in the given dropdown options.

Provide me a demo example of how to add product in django-oscar.

Answer (score 6):

You need to be logged in as a superuser and go to the store/dashboard URL
**DO NOT ADMINISTER THIS FROM THE NORMAL DJANGO ADMIN CONSOLE** (even though that answer was accepted?)

Here is an example of what this looks like in the included sandbox app
[image]

You need to add a category, product type, and partner and only then can you begin adding real products

Answer (score 2):

Check out this commit - it hasn't been merged to the Oscar's master yet, but should give you an idea on how you can create products programmatically, for instance when importing data.

https://github.com/ArtS/django-oscar/blob/3f9abaf8d5c179c385b90dfa463a35ff9f92f73c/docs/source/recipes/importing_a_catalogue.rst

Comment: I guess this answer is irrelevant here as user has only asked 'How to add product from the dashboard', not pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate page to administer product types, complete with a "Create new product type" button.

Using django-admin is not a good solution, you may be able to add product types and products through it, but you'll be missing out on any dashboard hooks into the normal process.

A look at the source code shows that whilst you may be able to add a product without a type (the FK is nullable), you may then experience other problems down the line as oscar expects only child products to have a null product_class.

```
    #: None for child products, they inherit their parent's product class
    product_class = models.ForeignKey(
        'catalogue.ProductClass', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=_('Product Type'), related_name="products",
        help_text=_("Choose what type of product this is"))
```

Definitely best to try to work with the system rather than around.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add atleast one product class /admin/catalogue/productclass/